# how to increase time duration of video file - objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, media

I am trying to merge audio and video files.

And  i have done it with below code.

```
NSString *audioUrl=videoAudioTrackPath;//[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"chalne" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSString *videoUrl=videoTempPath;//[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"whenever" ofType:@"mp4"];
    audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioUrl] options:nil];
    videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoUrl] options:nil];

    mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    compositionCommentaryTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio  preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [compositionCommentaryTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration) 
                                        ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] 
                                         atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo                                                                                    preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) 
                                   ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] 
                                    atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition 
                                                    presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];   

       //NSString *exportPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoName];
    NSString *exportPath = videoChangedPath;//[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Documents/"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"export.mov"];
    NSLog(@"%@",exportPath);

    NSURL    *exportUrl = [NSURL  fileURLWithPath:exportPath];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:exportPath]) 
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:exportPath error:nil];
    }

    _assetExport.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
    NSLog(@"file type %@",_assetExport.outputFileType);
    _assetExport.outputURL = exportUrl;
    _assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

    [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler: ^(void ) {      
        //[self btnListPressed:btnList];
        //[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(btnListPressed:) userInfo:nil repeats:FALSE];
    }];
```

**MY PURPOSE**
I want to change the voice of video file. for the shake of same I extracted video files audio track and changed its pitch and time duration. and then merged both file. In that way I am able to change the voice of Video file.

Now issue is that if I change the duration of audio then video does not match with it.

so I want to change the video time duration as per the audio file.

is there anyway to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the [insertEmptyTimeRange:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMutableComposition_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method to your mixComposition. This new TimeRange would be the extra time of your audio asset.